# How to use promises with angular 2 meteor

Tags: meteor, angular, promise

How does one promisify `Meteor.call` in angular-meteor?

Although there are pacakges for meteor that do similar things, they don't seem to be working out of the box with typescript (missing typings etc')

Answer (score 0):

```
export function meteorCallPromise(name, ...args): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meteor.call(name, ...args, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```